# WSL cron.d cronjobs file fails to work

Tags: cron

In WSL Ubuntu 16.04 ran `nano /etc/cron.d/cronjobs` and there I've written `* * * * * touch /var/www/html/myFile` (that's the only data in that file). I saved the file, waited a minute but no file is created in `/var/www/html/`.

I made sure the cron service is working (`service cron start`), got "OK" and waited another minute.

Yet still the `touch` doesn't effect --- no file by the name of `myFile` is created under /var/www/html.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike those in user's crontabs, jobs in `/etc/cron.d` (like those in the `/etc/crontab` system-wide crontab file) need an additional field to specify the user e.g.

```
* * * * * root touch /var/www/html/myFile
```

From `man 8 cron`:

```
   Additionally, in Debian, cron reads the files in the /etc/cron.d direc‐
   tory.  cron treats the files in /etc/cron.d as in the same way  as  the
   /etc/crontab  file  (they  follow the special format of that file, i.e.
   they  include  the  user  field).
```

Comment: I have added root in between the timing and command, and saved the file but sadly no change is seen. The file doesn't get created with `* * * * * root touch /var/www/html/myFile`.

Comment: @Arcticooling does WSL provide a /var/log/syslog file? if so, do you see cron attempt to run the job there (e.g. `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`)?