# Crontab in AWS ubuntu not running my task

Tags: cron, aws

We have an ubuntu instance in AWS and we tried with a simple command in crontab but nothing is happening.
We checked and found the service is running.We tried with other ID and Root but no luck
we added our task in /etc/crontab

Attached screenshot for reference.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJ6Qj.png)

Could some one help on this.

Comment: Are you editing the cron file directly? Or are you using `sudo crontab -e` to edit the file and have changes applied in save? 

Comment: First off, your cron job isn't set to run until the hour is straight up, you checked it at 43 minutes.  You would have to change the first `0` to a `*` if you want it to run every minute.

Comment: what is "date" supposed to do within crontab?

Comment: The format of the `/etc/crontab` file is different from that used by `crontab -e` - it needs an additional user field. See similar [WSL cron.d cronjobs file fails to work](https://askubuntu.com/a/997173/178692)

Comment: First would like to thank you for responding.   1. I used sudo crontab -e to edit and saved the file . 2. I i changed it to * instead of 0 and its still not working. 3. for the use of date, i am just trying with simple text to check if my cron is working. 4. I tried with user field also but no luck. Used root as a user. Just to mention i am able to run the same cron in my local system(ubuntu) but the same is not working in AWS ubuntu instance.